# groups and range and domain of function composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have a group $G$ and two elements $a,b$ in it,

$$f: G \rightarrow G, f(x) = ax$$
$$g: G \rightarrow G, g(x) = bx$$
Need to get their compositions and the range and domain of each:

$$f ∘ g = f(g(x)) = abx,$$ 
$$g ∘ f = g(f(x)) = bax$$

They are two different compositions, since the group is not defined as abelian. 
I would think that the range and domain of those are the same $G$ and $G$ in both though.
I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: To show that the range of $f\circ g$ is all of $G$, you will need to show that for every $y\in G$ you can find an $x$ such that $abx=y\dots$.

Comment: So $x = a^-1b^-1y$ for $f∘g$ and $x = b^-1a^-1y$ for $g∘f$

Comment: @Bob Another way is to think of $abx$ as $(ab)x$. So $f\circ g$ is a function that multiplies on the left by $(ab)$, a group element in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

If you define $f : G \to G$ by $f(x) = ax$ and $g : G \to G$ by $g(x) = bx$, the domains are $G$ by construction. The compositions are as follows:

$$f \circ g(x) = f \big(g(x)\big) = f(bx) = (ab) x$$ and $$g\circ f(x) = g \big(f(x)\big) = g(ax) = (ba)x$$ as you have shown.

These are both surjective group homomorphisms.

$f \circ g$ is surjective: if you choose an arbitrary $c \in G$, then choose $x := b^{-1}a^{-1}c$ and observe that $$f\big(g(x)\big) = (ab)x = (ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}c) = c.$$

$g \circ f$ is surjective: if you choose an arbitrary $c \in G$, then choose $x = a^{-1}b^{-1}c$ and observe that $$g \big(f(x)\big) = (ba)x = (ba)(a^{-1}b^{-1}c) = c.$$

So their ranges are both $G$.